# Mysterious black boxes covering text in table cells

Tags: tables, color

**(Edited with the minimalist reproducible code)**

I am writing a 2-column paper using `IEEEtrans.cls`. The paper contains a table whose rows have alternating background colors. The problem is, The first line of the first column of every row is covered by a mysterious black box as the figure below:

[image]

I can workaround this problem by opening the PDF with Acrobat and manually remove those black boxes. But I want to solve this problem at the typesetting stage.

**(Found how to solve the problem, but don't know why)**

I found that `arydshln` package causes the problem and solved it by not using this package. But still, I have no idea why and no idea what if I should use that package someday.

The code for the table is given below:

```
\documentclass[journal,comsoc,9pt]{IEEEtran}
\usepackage[table,xcdraw]{xcolor}
\usepackage{arydshln} % This causes the problem
\begin{document}
\nocite{*}
\begin{table}[]
\centering
\label{tab:table-label}
\begin{tabular}{ccc}
  \hline
  \rowcolor[HTML]{EFEFEF} 
  \textbf{Column 1}                                                                                                                  & \textbf{Column 2}                                                                                                                           \\ \hline
  \rowcolor[HTML]{FFFFFF} 
  \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}Cell\\ (1,1)\end{tabular}                 & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}Cell\\(1, 2)\end{tabular}                                                                         \\
  \rowcolor[HTML]{EFEFEF} 
  \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}Cell\\(2, 1)\end{tabular}           & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}Cell\\(2,2)\end{tabular}                                                             
  \end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Comment: See if you can reproduce it with a Hello Word document with the `article` class, if so, please post it. Else, use a hello World IEEE example with just the table and post that.

Comment: doesn't explain the black rules but why does your whole table consist of nested tabular, the markup is vastly more complicated than needed.

Comment: @Johannes_B Okay, I'll post the minimalist reproducible LaTex code soon.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Actually, I use https://www.tablesgenerator.com/ to build a table. That site uses a nested table to put multi-line text into a cell.

Comment: Quick note: Seems that a package `arydshln` causes the problem.

Comment: Isn't it easier to type simple tex markup directly than type the text into a generator that generates awful, over complicated tex?

Comment: on your note about `arydashln` that is why questions should always have a complete example document, the problem is in code you haven't shown.

Comment: Yes, sorry for just pasting the code of the table. I've updated the question.

Comment: Since you don't use the package, it shouldn't be in your code in the first place. Without looking closer, a table generator has been mentioned.  They produce code on what you said the tabular material should look like. A generator will add cells or spaces without merci. It does not have the slightest clue what the table is supposed to represent.

Comment: Probably Zarko, Bernard or Mico will provide a better table.

Comment: `arydshln` had to be loaded before `xcolor`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

since [Johannes_B](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/37907/johannes-b) provoke me :-) ...

- as mentioned in my comment above, `arydshln` had to be loaded before `xcolor`.

off-topic:

- context of table is not clear, so is not clear why you nested tabular environment in cells
- from provided code follows, that you like to have gray background of table
- below are two possible solutions

```
\documentclass[journal,comsoc,9pt]{IEEEtran}
\usepackage{arydshln} % had to be before xcolor
\usepackage[table,xcdraw]{xcolor}
\newcommand\mycell[1]{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}#1\end{tabular}}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}[htb]
\definecolor{mygray}{HTML}{EFEFEF}
\centering
    \caption{}
\label{tab:table-label}
\begin{tabular}{*{2}{>{\columncolor{mygray}}c}}
  \hline
\textbf{Column 1}   & \textbf{Column 2} \\
    \hline
Cell                & Cell              \\
(1,1)               & (1, 2)            \\
    \hline
Cell                & Cell              \\
(2,1)               & (2, 2)            \\
    \hline
  \end{tabular}
\end{table}

\begin{table}[htb]
   \caption{}
\definecolor{mygray}{HTML}{EFEFEF}.
\centering
\label{tab:table-label}
\begin{tabular}{*{2}{>{\columncolor{mygray}}c}}
  \hline
\textbf{Column 1}       & \textbf{Column 2}     \\
    \hline
\mycell{Cell\\ (1,1)}   & \mycell{Cell\\ (1,2)} \\
    \hline
\mycell{Cell\\ (2,1)}   & \mycell{Cell\\ (2,2)} \\                                                                             \hline
  \end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the answer. What I meant to use nested tabular is to handle multiple-lined text into cells, but they are not guaranteed to have the same number of lines. So, the second solution is what I looking for.