# Longtable and arydshln produces black box

Tags: longtable, arydshln

What I want to accomplish is to draw a dashed line inside longtable.
What is strange is that when `arydshln` package is loaded I receive a black box for the first row (header) in the first cell. I guess the problem occurs with the combination of longtable, arydshln and `\rowcolor`.

Is there any solution or any other package that offers dashed lines inside tables except longtabu?

Here my MWE:

```
\documentclass[paper=a4,fontsize=18pt]{article}
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{
    % verbose,
    landscape,      % page orientation (landscape or portrait)
    a4paper,        % paper size
    tmargin=20mm,   % page top margin
    bmargin=20mm,   % page bottom margin
    lmargin=5mm,   % page left margin
    rmargin=5mm % page right maring
}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[defaultsans]{opensans} %font
\usepackage[T1, T2A]{fontenc}
\usepackage[english,bulgarian]{babel}
\usepackage{longtable} % use this table
\usepackage{colortbl}
\usepackage{makecell}
\usepackage[lutf8x]{luainputenc}
\usepackage{arydshln}


\begin{document}
\begin{longtable}[l] {|
p{30mm}|
p{30mm}|
p{30mm}|
p{15mm}|
p{15mm}|
p{15mm}|
p{30mm}|
p{30mm}|}
\hline\rowcolor{red}
\raisebox{-0.7mm}[0mm][12mm]{ \thead[l]{ Test \textnumero } } &
\raisebox{-0.7mm}[0mm][12mm]{ \thead[l]{ Папка \textnumero } } &
\raisebox{-4mm}[0mm][12mm]{ \thead[l]{ Дата на \\ въвеждане \\ на документа } } &
\raisebox{-2.3mm}[0mm][12mm]{ \thead[l]{ Потре- \\ бител } } &
\raisebox{-2.3mm}[0mm][12mm]{ \thead[l]{ Сметка \\ дебит } } &
\raisebox{-2.3mm}[0mm][12mm]{ \thead[l]{ Сметка \\ кредит } } &
\raisebox{-2.3mm}[0mm][12mm]{ \thead[r]{ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ Стойност \\ дебит } } &
\raisebox{-2.3mm}[0mm][12mm]{ \thead[r]{ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ Стойност \\ кредит } }
\\ \hline \endhead 
test & test &
test & test &
test & test &
test & test\\ \hdashline
\end{longtable}
\end{document}
```

Comment: This  table can't fit on a4paper, even in landscape!

Comment: I can see that @Bernard. This is a MWE of the document. 
This is not the current problem.

Comment: I fixed it and now can fit. I still dont have any solution to the main problem.

Comment: Have a look at this question, perhaps: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/400909/mysterious-black-boxes-covering-text-in-table-cells Looks like you need to load xcolor first.

Comment: This is not a problem with `arydshln`, but with `makecell`: it sometimes has problems with color in tables. A workaround consists in replacing  `thead` with `\Centerstack` from the `stackengine` package. I could propose a code, but I don't quite understand what you're trying to achieve with all these `\raisebox` in column heads.

Comment: Thank you for helping. What I am trying to achieve with raisebox is to align the text at the top.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it in a simpler way, `makecell` is not needed and also all those `\raisebox` commands. With the help of suitable struts we can get some separation between the header cells and the borders.

Avoid `luainputenc`: it's for legacy documents and should not be used in newer ones.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{
  % verbose,
  landscape,    % page orientation (landscape or portrait)
  a4paper,      % paper size
  tmargin=20mm, % page top margin
  bmargin=20mm, % page bottom margin
  lmargin=5mm,  % page left margin
  rmargin=5mm,  % page right margin
}
\usepackage[english,bulgarian]{babel}
\usepackage{longtable} % use this table
\usepackage{colortbl}
\usepackage{arydshln}
\usepackage{fontspec}

\setmainfont{OpenSans}

\newcommand\mytopstrut{\rule{0pt}{2.5ex}}
\newcommand\mybotstrut{\rule[-1.5ex]{0pt}{1.5ex}}

\begin{document}
\begin{longtable}[l] {
  |
  p{30mm}|
  p{30mm}|
  p{30mm}|
  p{15mm}|
  p{15mm}|
  p{15mm}|
  p{30mm}|
  p{30mm}|
}
\hline\rowcolor{red}
\raggedright\mytopstrut Test \textnumero &
\raggedright\mytopstrut Папка \textnumero &
\raggedright\mytopstrut Дата на въвеждане на документа\mybotstrut &
\raggedright\mytopstrut Потре- бител &
\raggedright\mytopstrut Сметка дебит &
\raggedright\mytopstrut Сметка кредит &
\raggedleft\mytopstrut Стойност \\ дебит &
\raggedleft\mytopstrut Стойност \\ кредит \tabularnewline
\hline
\endhead 
test & test &
test & test &
test & test &
test & test\\ \hdashline
\end{longtable}
\end{document}
```

[image]